# Custom rule Laravel Livewire

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire, laravel-7, laravel-validation

In Laravel Livewire I added a custom youtube video validation rule. It works very well, the problem is that I need it to be nullable and if I add in the validate nullable it gives me an error and I can't find how to solve this problem.

**Input:**

```
<input wire:model="video" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Url youtube">
```

**Rule:**

```
 public function passes($attribute, $value)
        {
            return (bool) preg_match('/^.*(youtu.be\/|v\/|u\/\w\/|embed\/|watch\?v=|\&v=|\?v=)([^#\&\?]*).*/',$value);
        }
```

**Validate:**

```
'video' => 'nullable', new RuleYoutube,
```

Removing nullable works fine, but the field is not required. And with the nullable property I get the following error:

> No property found for validation: [0]

Any suggestion? Thank you very much for spending time in my consultation

Comment: That's bad syntax. It should be `'video' => [ 'nullable', new RuleYoutube ],` to ensure both rules apply to video

Comment: thank you very much, that was it. If you want to publish your answer, I will rate you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I solved this issue was to utilise Livewire's `validateOnly` method with an *invokable* validation Rule.

```
public function updated($propertyName)
{
    if($propertyName == 'enquiry.contact_email'){
        $this->validateOnly('enquiry.contact_email', [
            'enquiry.contact_email' => [new DelimitedEmail, 'required']
        ]);
    }
}
```

Invokable rule:
`php artisan make:rule DelimitedEmail --invokable`

Code:

```
class DelimitedEmail implements InvokableRule
{
    public function __invoke($attribute, $value, $fail)
    {
        $func = function(string $value): string {
            return trim($value);
        };
        if(str_contains($value, ',')) {
            $emails = array_map($func,explode(',',$value));
            foreach($emails as $email) {
                if(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) $fail('This field has an invalid email address.');
            }
        } else {
            if(!filter_var($value, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) $fail('That is an invalid email address.');
        }
    }
}
```

[image: invokable custom validation rule in Laravel Livewire]

Comment: Were you able to register with `Validator::extend('delimited_email', ...)` and write `'enquiry.contact_email' => 'delimited_email|required'`?

Comment: @bilogic in the $rules you just use `required` or any other standard validation and then you use the `updated` method as noted above via `validateOnly` to invoke the custom rule.

Comment: thanks, I realized that `update` was unsuitable for me as I needed it to run at `submit`

Answer (score 1):

Either you can have the validation in a single string pipe separated or in an array.

```
'video' => ['nullable', new RuleYoutube],
```

Check out [livewire validation docs](https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/input-validation).

Comment: To me, this is not working, and I can't find any mention of it in the documentation.

Comment: This does not work in Livewire, the `$rules` array complains about the use of new expressions being used.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add a dynamic custom validation rule, you can use the **function syntax for declaring rules**, instead of declaring it as a variable, which will cause error while using 'new' expressions.

```
protected function rules()
{
    return [
        'video' => ['nullable', new RuleYoutube],
    ];
}
```

Here's the [Documentation link](https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/input-validation)